# $u=f(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+g(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

write the Partial Differential Equation his general solution:

$u=f(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+g(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)$

My try:

${\partial{u}\over {\partial{x}}}=\cos{\alpha} \ f^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+\cos{\alpha} \ g^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)$

${\partial{u}\over {\partial{y}}}=\sin{\alpha} \ f^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+\sin{\alpha} \ g^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)$

${\partial{u}\over {\partial{t}}}=-a \ f^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+a \ g^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)$

and

${\partial^{2}{u}\over {\partial{x}^2}}=\cos^2{\alpha} \ [ f^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+g^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)]$

${\partial^2{u}\over {\partial{y}^2}}=\sin^2{\alpha}[ \ f^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+\ g^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)]$

${\partial^2{u}\over {\partial{t}^2}}=a^2 [ \ f^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}-at)+ \ g^{\prime}(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha}+at)]$

then I got:

\begin{equation}{\partial^{2}{u}\over {\partial{x}^2}}+{\partial^2{u}\over {\partial{y}^2}}-{1\over {a}^2}{\partial^2{u}\over {\partial{t}^2}}=0\end{equation}

true?

Comment: Seems to be. In general, the form of the required ODE should be determined. For example, in your question, it'd be more correct if the question is: Write the ODE satisfied by $\partial_x^2u,$ $\partial_y^2u$ and
$\partial_t^2u.$

Comment: Sorry, But I don't speak English Well, are you mean It's correct answer, but this answer $\partial^2_x {u}+\partial^2_y {u}-{1\over {a}^2}\partial^2_t {u}=0$ more correct ?

Comment: The answer is correct, but the question should be clearer